# Test if points lie on a 2D fitted plane in 4D

Tags: matlab, vector, geometry, linear-algebra

Suppose I have 3+ coplanar but not collinear points in R^4. To find the 2D plane (not hyperplane) in which they all lie, I used the following plane fit algorithm from MatlabCentral:

```
function [n,V,p] = affine_fit(X)
    % Computes the plane that fits best (least square of the normal distance
    % to the plane) a set of sample points.
    % INPUTS:
    % X: a N by 3 matrix where each line is a sample point
    %OUTPUTS:
    %n : a unit (column) vector normal to the plane
    %V : a 3 by 2 matrix. The columns of V form an orthonormal basis of the plane
    %p : a point belonging to the plane
    %NB: this code actually works in any dimension (2,3,4,...)
    %Author: Adrien Leygue
    %Date: August 30 2013

    % the mean of the samples belongs to the plane
    p = mean(X,1);
    % The samples are reduced:
    R = bsxfun(@minus,X,p);
    % Computation of the principal directions of the samples cloud
    [V,D] = eig(R'*R);
    % Extract the output from the eigenvectors
    n = V(:,1);
    V = V(:,2:end);
end
```

I employed the algorithm in a higher dimension than specified, so X is a 4x4 matrix which holds 4 points in 4 coordinate dimensions. The generated output is something like this.

```
[n,V,p] = affine_fit(X);

n = -0.0252
    -0.0112
     0.9151
    -0.4024

V = 0.9129   -0.3475    0.2126
    0.3216    0.2954   -0.8995
    0.1249    0.3532    0.1493
    0.2180    0.8168    0.3512

p = -0.9125    1.0526    0.2325   -0.0621
```

What I want to do now is find out if other points of my choosing are part of the plane, too. I'm sure it's fairly easy given the information above, yet at this point I only know that I need two linear equations to describe a 2D plane in 4D or parametric equations of two variables. I can set them up in theory, but writing up the code has been problematic. Perhaps there is a more straightforward way to test this in matlab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Matlab function [pca](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/stats/pca.html) (see for example [here](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/stats/examples/fitting-an-orthogonal-regression-using-principal-components-analysis.html)). For example, you can determine the basis of your plane, the normal vectors to your plane and a point **m** on the plane as follows:

```
coeff = pca(X);
basis = coeff(:,1:2);
normals = coeff(:,3:4);
m = mean(X);
```

To check if a point **p** lies in this plane, it suffices to verify that `m-p` is orthogonal (dot product equal to zero) to the normal vectors onto the plane using [dot](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dot.html).

Comment: Ah, perfect, thanks! So, m-p has to be orthogonal to each of the two normals, correct? And if X is a 4x4 matrix made up of 4 points and coeff =  pca(X) only gives a 3x4 matrix, can I conclude that two of the points were collinear?

Comment: I believe you can. You can always check if the points are collinear by verifying the rank of X.